# unordered_map with reference as value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, reference, unordered-map

Is it legal to have an unordered_map with the value type being a reference C++11?

For example `std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClass&>`

I have managed to get this to compile with VS2013 however I'm not sure whether it's supposed to as it is causing some strange runtime errors. For example `vector subscript out of range` is thrown when trying to `erase` an element.

Some googling resulted in finding out that you can't have a vector of references but I can't find anything about an unordered_map.

## Update

Further experimentation has shown that the `vector subscript out of range` was not related to the unordered_map of references as it was a bug in my code.

Comment: Just use `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @T.C. Ok, but is using a standard reference for the value in an unordered_map valid C++11?

Comment: You may declare such a map, and most but not all operations on it should work. You can't use `operator[]` as it requires the mapped type to be `DefaultConstructible` (and references aren't). You can't brace-initialize this map, or assign one map to another, as this requires mapped type to be `CopyAssignable`.

Comment: Clang compiles it just fine too.

Comment: @Igor Most containers does not require (Copy/Move)Assignable, they work fine with (Copy/Move)Constructible and assignement or brace initialisation is fine. operator[] of maps are the only exception needing DefaultConstructible and (Copy/Move)Assignable.

Comment: @galop1n Yes, I was mistaken. `CopyAssignable` is a requirement for `a = il` construct, not for `a(il)` - that is, assigning from initializer list, not constructing from one.

Comment: @Igor That's not even necessary, [proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d086d75ac26aa054)

Comment: @galop1n Well, it might not be necessary with a particular compiler and standard library implementation. But a program that takes advantage of this flexibility is not a valid C++11 program. Practically speaking, it's non-portable; it happens to work with this implementation, but it's not guaranteed to work with other conforming implementations.

Comment: @igor i know a test is not a pure proof, i did look at cppreference that is quite correct on that kind of details, i will look tomorow the iso, but i really do not see why the standard would put that unneeded restriction here when it always target the minimum vital ones everywhere else

Comment: @igor ok found it, the requirement exists. Apparently to allow implementation to optimise a bit by bypassing a destructrion/construction cycle, that make sense with some containers but is unlikely to happens with associative ones. Still yes, not a good idea to depends on it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You should make an answer of your first comment, it was very useful and I would be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` and `unordered_map` are fine with references, here a working [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb47629da71dad2f) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using UMap = std::unordered_map<int,int&>;

int main() {
    int a{1}, b{2}, c{3};
    UMap foo { {1,a},{2,b},{3,c} };

    // insertion and deletion are fine
    foo.insert( { 4, b } );
    foo.emplace( 5, d );
    foo.erase( 4 );
    foo.erase( 5 );

    // display b, use find as operator[] need DefaultConstructible
    std::cout << foo.find(2)->second << std::endl;

    // update b and show that the map really map on it
    b = 42;
    std::cout << foo.find(2)->second << std::endl;

    // copy is fine
    UMap bar = foo; // default construct of bar then operator= is fine too
    std::cout << bar.find(2)->second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with objects. Trying this with std::thread just gives me `error: value-initialization of reference type ‘std::thread&’`