# Is it legal to construct an unordered_map holding references?

Tags: c++, reference, containers, unordered-map

In general STL containers cannot hold non-`CopyAssignable` types such as references. If I construct the container in a way that no copy should take place, then is the code valid. It compiles with `std=c++11` and `c++14` with some version of gcc-7.2, but is the following valid or can I expect it to break with a library upgrade? Should I use `reference_wrapper` in this case?

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct S {};

void use (S&) {}

void test() {
    S s1, s2;
    const std::unordered_map<int, S&> m{{0, s1}, {1, s2}};
    use(m.at(0));
}
```

---

**Edit** I really do need a reference to the standard. Works for me too is not enough, if a standard-conforming update of the compiler/standard library can break the code. So the answer given for ["unordered_map with reference as value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719044/unordered-map-with-reference-as-value) is not enough for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unordered\_map with reference as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719044/unordered-map-with-reference-as-value)

Comment: in general containers require CopyAssignable not only for construction, but also many algorithms may not work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an answer myself for this specific use case:

The [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) standard at clause 23.5.4.3 for unordered_map element access specifically omits listing any requirements for the `mapped_type`, that is `S&`, while with `operator[]` it must be `DefaultConstructible`.

> ```
> mapped_type& at(const key_type& k);
> const mapped_type& at(const key_type& k) const;
> ```
>
> *Returns*: A reference to `x.second`, where `x` is the (unique) element whose key is equivalent to `k`.
>
> *Throws*: An exception object of type `out_of_range` if no such element is present.

[C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) also indirectly says something to this effect in 26.5.4.3 and 26.5.4.4.

Therefore, the above code **should** work with any standard implementation.

**However**, it is true – as pointed out in the comments – that mutating the container after construction or applying any algorithm that requires constructing or assigning the container's `value_type` or `mapped_type` will not work.